# Right Reset Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata

How do you simulate an ordinary turing machine using a right reset turing machine ?
*(*A right reset machine is in which you can move left and reset to right end position*. Moreover the tape is unbounded on left but it is bounded on right)*

Comment: Just to clarify the input in the right-reset TM (RRTM) is still written left-to-right and the tape is infinite to the left. I am assuming here that the tape of your ordinary TM is infinite to the left also.

Comment: @Russel yes, the input is still written left to right and it is unbounded on the left but not on right.

Comment: The way I understand the setup, your RRTM will start with the head on the right most symbol of the input. Is that correct?

Comment: you can at be any state but from there you can only move to the left but not on right so the transition func can be σ(q,a) = σ(q,a,{left,reset})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complete description of the simulation would be tedious. In the following I will only be sketching a strategy that allows you to simulate a movement to the right, which seems to be where the difficulty lies.

If the head is in some tape cell and you want to move it to the right you can do the following:

1. Add a "mark", which we will call $\alpha$, to the symbol in the current cell (formally this introduces a new symbol $x_\alpha$ for each symbol $x$ in the tape alphabet).
2. Reset the head to the rightmost tape cell.
3. Place a $\beta$ mark on the current tape cell.
4. Scan the tape from right to left, while remembering whether the previous symbol had a $\beta$ mark. Stop as soon as you reach the symbol with the $\alpha$-mark.
5. If the previous symbol had a $\beta$ mark, then:

   5.1. Remove the $\alpha$ mark from the current symbol.

   5.2. Reset the head position.

   5.3. Scan the tape from right to left until you find the symbol with the $\beta$ mark.

   5.4. Remove the $\beta$ mark. The head is now one location to the left w.r.t. its position at the beginning of this procedure.
6. Otherwise (the previous symbol did not have a $\beta$ mark):

   6.1. Reset the head position.

   6.2. Scan the tape from right to left until you find the symbol with the $\beta$ mark.

   6.3. Remove the $\beta$ mark from the current symbol.

   6.4. Move left.

   6.5. Add the $\beta$ mark to the current symbol.

   6.6. Reset the head position and repeat from instruction 4.

Comment: Was typing my answer (which seems to be the same as yours) on my phone and did not realize you already posted an answer and was accepted too.

Comment: @Steven gave a really good answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's more organized and easy to follow than mine.

Answer (score 1):

The right reset TM (RRTM) based on your setup lacks the ability to move one position to the right. To simulate this, when the RRTM is at cell $c$ and needs to move to $c_r$, the cell to the right, it marks the content of cell $c$ i.e. put a dot on top of the symbol on $c$, move to a special state $q_{search}$, then do a right reset. Now, it finds $c_r$. To do this, it marks the current cell $c_i$ using two dots and move left to $c_j$. If $c_j$ has a dot then the TM is on $c$ and the previously marked cell,  $c_i$, is $c_r$. The TM enters state $q_{found}$ and reset right. It continuously moves left until it find $c_i$ again (by looking for the cell with two dots). It changes the two dots to a single dot then move left and remove the dot from this current cell (this is cell $c$). It then right reset again and move left continuously until the cell with a dot is found, which is $c_r$. The TM can now proceed normaly.

If in case $c_j$ has no dot then it is not $c$ and the the cell marked with two dots is not $c_r$. The TM right resets and move left until it get to $c_i$ (the cell with two dots) . It removes the two dots in $c_i$, move left and let this next cell be the new $c_i$ and repeat the process above to check if $c_i$ is $c_r$.

Comment: Thank you for contribution.